# Magento admin grid column formatting - renderer?

Tags: php, magento

I want the sales_order_create grid to show both the price and special price in the same column, and I've done so by adding:

```
    ->addAttributeToSelect('special_price')
```

To the _prepareCollection() function, and then adding:

```
    $this->addColumn('special_price', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Special Price'),
        'sortable'     => false,
        'index'        => array('price', 'special_price'),
        'type'         => 'concat',
        'separator'    => ' -- ',
        'width'        => '140px',
    ));
```

To the _prepareColumns() function.

This works! The result is a new column which, as an example, displays:

79.9800 -- 34.9900

How do I format this so it's in a currency format? £xx.xx

Also, is it possible to style it? So it looks like this: £79.98 (£34.99)

If it's not possible to style, just in currency format would be great.

I think it's something to do with the renderer but I'm new to Magento so would need it explaining in a basic way if thats ok.

Thanks

Comment: usually you get the price format by setting `'type' => 'price'`, no clue if you can set two types or can forgo on the concat type somehow. Otherwise I think writing your own renderer would work... I got no tutorials handy right now, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get this working, my code is horrible, but it may help anyone who stumbles across this in the future.

I looked at the price column and saw:

```
'renderer'  => 'adminhtml/sales_order_create_search_grid_renderer_price',
```

After navigating to app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer I noticed a concat renderer.

I copied Concat.php from this directory and created a local version, I named it Special.php to avoid any conflicts:

/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer/Special.php

I then added this renderer to my special_price column:

```
'renderer'  => 'adminhtml/sales_order_create_search_grid_renderer_special',
```

My Special.php code is as follows (warning: this code is pretty horrible, but it works so I'm happy):

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Special
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
/**
 * Renders grid column
 *
 * @param   Varien_Object $row
 * @return  string
 */
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
    $dataArr = array();

    foreach ($this->getColumn()->getIndex() as $index) {
        if ($data = $row->getData($index)) {
            //$dataArr[] = $data;
                            $dataArr[] = number_format((float)$data, 2, '.', '');
        }
    }
    $data = join($this->getColumn()->getSeparator(), $dataArr);
    // TODO run column type renderer

            $price = '';
            $special = '';

            if (strlen($dataArr[0]) > 0) {

            if (strlen($dataArr[1]) > 0) {
              $price = '<span style="text-decoration:line-through">&pound;' . $dataArr[0] . '</span>';
              $special = ' &pound;' . $dataArr[1];
            }
            else {
              $price = '&pound;' . $dataArr[0];
              $special = '';
            }

            }

            return $price . $special;
}
}
```

The result is if there is no price (grouped product) the entry is blank, if there is no special the entry is the RRP and if there is a special the entry is <strike>RRP</strike> special price

The code I'm sure can be improved but it works